# How how do I link live Shoutcast broadcast to website?

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-audio, shoutcast

I am new to coding and am trying to set up a streaming audio option so that visitors may listen to a weekly live broadcast directly from a website but most browsers are blocking it from running.

The live stream is coming from Shoutcast as an HTTP:// not an HTTPS:// which is causing an insecure mixed content issue.

The stream works fine on Firefox on the live site, but will not work on any other browser tested.

I do get the console message on Chrome that it was automatically upgraded to HTTPS://, and from what I understand I should just have to change my code to HTTPS:// for it to work, but it is not, and I could be wrong.

Here is my original code:

```
  <audio
      controls
      src="http://djefo.lightmanstreams.com:8020/;"
      type="audio/mpeg"
   ></audio>
```

Are there any suggestions on how I can make the stream work on Chrome at least?

Comment: You'll need to use HTTPS for your streams if you want to use HTTPS for your page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, unless you upgrade your shoutcast streaming package, you will not be able to use https to avoid mixed content issue. From my experience of shoucast/icecast streaming, I can say you have to upgrade your package to the certain package which provides **SSL** for your streaming URL.

Comment: thank you, I will reach out to the owner and let him know.

Comment: Yes, you should contact with the shoucast streaming provider. And it was my pleasure that I could help you on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Latest Shoutcast version (2.6.1 build 777: https://yp.shoutcast.com/v/2_6_1) does support SSL out of the box on Linux, so you can get a free SSL certificate from Letsencrypt and use it with Shoutcast.
2. You can configure Apache or Nginx as SSL proxy for your non-ssl SHoutcast stream, see this answer: [Web radio stream proxying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011675/web-radio-stream-proxying/40211021#40211021)